# Azure Data Factory - Merge 2 JSON string columns into a new column

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I have a Delimited Text source data which contains 2 JSON String columns.

I need to merge these 2 columns into a new JSON string column.

Tried `Copy data` but it supports only 1 to 1 mapping. Then took a look in `Derived Column` of `Data flow`, but it only has `concat` function to pad 2 strings.

For example I have my source data like:

```
|      a       |      b       |
|--------------|--------------|
| [{"foo": 0}] | [{"bar": 1}] |
| [{"baz": 2}] |              |
```

And I want to merge Column `a` and `b` into `c`:

```
|            c             |
|--------------------------|
| [{"foo": 0}, {"bar": 1}] |
| [{"baz": 2}]             |
```

Is there anyway to do this in Data Factory?

Comment: Data Flow derived column is almost certainly what you want, but it's a little unclear from the question. Can you add samples of the source data and the desired output?

Comment: @JoelCochran I've updated the question, basically I want to do something like `c = [*json.loads(a), *json.loads(b)]` in Python

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, unfortunately I don't have any suggestions on how to accomplish this.